# Do the "w" and "s" key bindings work differently in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I've been working on translating a version of the game "Pong", that I built for an online Python class using CodeSkulptor, into a "desktop" python script using Tkinter, as a means to teach myself how to use Tkinter.  I've managed to pretty much get the entire game working, except for the left (player 1) paddle.  I think I have the key bindings correct, as the right (player 2) paddle works as expected, in that when you hold down the "Up" or "Down" arrow keys, the paddle moves until it hits the upper or lower bounds of the canvas, or stops when either key is released.  I'm passing the key presses to the keydown and keyup handlers, where I check to see which key was pressed/released, and act accordingly.  What's baffling to me is that if I map the left paddle movement to different keys (say "a" or "d", or the "Up" or "Down" arrows, for example), it works as expected, but it refuses to work when I have the "w" and "s" keys mapped.  Does anyone have any idea why that might be, or what I may have done wrong?

The code I've provided below is a basic example I put together, that demonstrates this issue, and the paddle movement that I'm trying to achieve (it pretty much mirrors my Pong project).  The right-side paddle moves correctly, where the left side paddle does not.  Thanks in advance for your help!

```
from Tkinter import *
import random


WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500
PAD_WIDTH = 10
PAD_HEIGHT = 80
HALF_PAD_WIDTH = PAD_WIDTH / 2
HALF_PAD_HEIGHT = PAD_HEIGHT / 2


class Example(Frame, object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Example, self).__init__(master)

        self._paddle1_pos = 200
        self._paddle2_pos = 200
        self._paddle1_vel = 0
        self._paddle2_vel = 0

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        scn_cent_height = self.master.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - HEIGHT // 2
        scn_cent_width = self.master.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - WIDTH // 2
        self.master.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (WIDTH, HEIGHT, scn_cent_width, scn_cent_height))
        self.master.minsize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

        self.master.title("Example Pong Paddles")

        self._canvasFrame = Frame(self.master)
        self._canvasFrame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        self._canvas = Canvas(self._canvasFrame, bg="black", highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
        self._canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.update_idletasks()

        # Key handlers
        self.master.bind("<KeyPress>", self.keydown)
        self.master.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.keyup)

        while True:
            self._canvas.after(1)
            self._canvas.delete("all")
            self.draw()
            self._canvas.update()


    def draw(self):
        self._cheight = self._canvasFrame.winfo_height()
        self._cwidth = self._canvasFrame.winfo_width()

        # Draw mid line and gutters
        self._rline = self._canvas.create_line(self._cwidth / 2, 0, self._cwidth / 2, self._cheight, width=1, fill="White")
        self._mline = self._canvas.create_line(PAD_WIDTH, 0, PAD_WIDTH, self._cheight, width=1, fill="White")
        self._lline = self._canvas.create_line(self._cwidth - PAD_WIDTH, 0, self._cwidth - PAD_WIDTH, self._cheight, width=1, fill="White")

        # Update paddle's vertical position, keep paddle on the screen
        # Paddle 1 - Check height and update position
        if self._paddle1_pos + self._paddle1_vel >= HALF_PAD_HEIGHT and self._paddle1_pos + self._paddle1_vel <= HEIGHT - HALF_PAD_HEIGHT:
            self._paddle1_pos += self._paddle1_vel

        # Paddle 2 - Check height and update position
        if self._paddle2_pos + self._paddle2_vel >= HALF_PAD_HEIGHT and self._paddle2_pos + self._paddle2_vel <= HEIGHT - HALF_PAD_HEIGHT:
            self._paddle2_pos += self._paddle2_vel

        # Draw paddles
        self._p1paddle = self._canvas.create_line([HALF_PAD_WIDTH, self._paddle1_pos - HALF_PAD_HEIGHT],
                                                  [HALF_PAD_WIDTH, self._paddle1_pos + HALF_PAD_HEIGHT], width=PAD_WIDTH, fill="White")
        self._p2paddle = self._canvas.create_line([self._cwidth - HALF_PAD_WIDTH, self._paddle2_pos - HALF_PAD_HEIGHT],
                                                  [self._cwidth - HALF_PAD_WIDTH, self._paddle2_pos + HALF_PAD_HEIGHT], width=PAD_WIDTH, fill="White")


        # Draw paddles
        self._p1paddle = self._canvas.create_line([HALF_PAD_WIDTH, self._paddle1_pos - HALF_PAD_HEIGHT],
                                                  [HALF_PAD_WIDTH, self._paddle1_pos + HALF_PAD_HEIGHT], width=PAD_WIDTH, fill="White")
        self._p2paddle = self._canvas.create_line([self._cwidth - HALF_PAD_WIDTH, self._paddle2_pos - HALF_PAD_HEIGHT],
                                                  [self._cwidth - HALF_PAD_WIDTH, self._paddle2_pos + HALF_PAD_HEIGHT], width=PAD_WIDTH, fill="White")


    def keydown(self, key):
        key = key.keysym

        if key == "w":
            self._paddle1_vel = -10
        elif key == "s":
            self._paddle1_vel = 10
        elif key == "Up":
            self._paddle2_vel = -10
        elif key == "Down":
            self._paddle2_vel = 10


    def keyup(self, key):
        key = key.keysym

        if key == "w":
            self._paddle1_vel = 0
        elif key == "s":
            self._paddle1_vel = 0
        elif key == "Up":
            self._paddle2_vel = 0
        elif key == "Down":
            self._paddle2_vel = 0




def main():
    root = Tk()
    example = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you have caps lock on? If so, `'w'` and `'W'` aren't the same.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me (Linux, python3.6 ).

Comment: I just did a sanity to check to make sure I wasn't using caps lock before, and had the same results.  As another sanity check, I also tried running it using the command line (instead of Spyder), and came up with the same results there, as well.  I'm running python 2.7 on MacOSX Mojave (10.14.3), btw.  Maybe it's something weird with MacOS?  Fwiw, I also have an Apple wireless magic keyboard connected to my laptop, though I've tested it both on that keyboard and on my laptop's built in keyboard, with no difference.

Comment: Are you sure about the 2.7? Your tkinter imports are for python3. You can use them the way you have them if you install compatibility packages like `six`.

Comment: @Novel, you're right, I had accidentally typoed the import statement.  Thanks for catching that.  I fixed it in my code above, and also retested with it corrected, though I still ran into the same problem.  Just for background, I use Anaconda and my root python install is 2.7.

Comment: Try adding `print(repr(key))` to the keydown() method and tell us what gets printed when you press 'w'.

Comment: @Novel, if placed before the ```key = key.keysym``` statement, it returns a tkinter event instance, such as ```<Tkinter.Event instance at 0x10e736170>```.  If placed after the ```key = key.keysym``` statement, it returns ```'s'``` or ```'w'```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to add, for the benefit of anyone else who runs into this problem, that I was able to trace the source of it back to my Anaconda virtual environments (I have one each for Python 2 and Python 3).  In testing, I was able to reproduce this issue when specifically using those environments, but was unable to reproduce it when using Python 2 (mac framework build) or Python 3 (installed via Brew) outside of Anaconda.  I wiped out both Anaconda virtual environments in case something was messed up there, and rebuilt them both (i.e. clean install of both Python 2 and 3), and was still able to reproduce this issue (without installing any additional modules).  I can only surmise that there is something different between the python(s) that is/are installed by Anaconda, and those that either are part of the system framework, or installed separately.

Also, just to note, it turns out when I successfully tested on Python 3 in @Novel's above comment, I inadvertently tested on the system Python 3, rather than in the Anaconda Python 3 virtual environment.

**EDIT:**
It turns out this problem is actually due to the version of Tkinter (Tcl/Tk) that my python installs were using.  The python framework on my laptop was using Tk 8.5.9, whereas the Anaconda installs are using 8.6.8.  In testing, I ran into this issue when running my Pong script in python 2.7.16 and 3.7.3 with Tk 8.6.8, but it ran perfectly fine on the same python versions with Tk 8.5.9.  I'm not sure if this is an issue with Tk, or some incompatibility between Tk 8.6.8 and the MacOS framework (since the framework natively uses 8.5.9).

Answer (score -1):

Your code is very messy and needs to be refactored, so I did that. Some notes:

- The biggest note is that instead of clearing the screen and redrawing everything, it's much neater and performs much better if you draw objects once and then simply move them around.
- Use tkinter's mainloop; don't make your own and update it manually. The  `update()` or `update_idletasks()` methods are last resort; normal code does not have them. Use tkinter's mainloop via `after()` instead. This will make your window much more reactive.
- Python2 Tkinter classes are old-style, do not force them to be new-style by adding an object inheritance.
- the canvas frame is useless, so I removed that.
- keeping the keys in a dictionary frees up a lot of repeated code.
- Prefixing all your variable names with `_` does nothing and makes it hard to read and type; leave that off.

-

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk # python3 detected
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk # python2 detected

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500
PAD_WIDTH = 10
PAD_HEIGHT = 80
VELOCITY = 10
HALF_PAD_WIDTH = PAD_WIDTH // 2
HALF_PAD_HEIGHT = PAD_HEIGHT // 2

P1_UP = 111 # Up arrow key
P1_DOWN = 116 # Down arrrow key
P2_UP = 25 # 'w' key
P2_DOWN = 39 # 's' key

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.keys = {}
        self.initUI()

        # Key handlers
        self.master.bind("<KeyPress>", self.keydown)
        self.master.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.keyup)

        self.draw() # add the game loop to the mainloop

    def initUI(self):
        scn_cent_height = self.master.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - HEIGHT // 2
        scn_cent_width = self.master.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - WIDTH // 2
        self.master.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (WIDTH, HEIGHT, scn_cent_width, scn_cent_height))
        self.master.minsize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

        self.master.title("Example Pong Paddles")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="black", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Draw mid line and gutters
        self.rline = self.canvas.create_line(WIDTH//2, 0, WIDTH//2, HEIGHT, width=1, fill="White")
        self.mline = self.canvas.create_line(PAD_WIDTH, 0, PAD_WIDTH, HEIGHT, width=1, fill="White")
        self.lline = self.canvas.create_line(WIDTH - PAD_WIDTH, 0, WIDTH - PAD_WIDTH, HEIGHT, width=1, fill="White")

        # Draw paddles
        self.p1paddle = self.canvas.create_line([HALF_PAD_WIDTH, HEIGHT//2 - HALF_PAD_HEIGHT],
                                                  [HALF_PAD_WIDTH, HEIGHT//2 + HALF_PAD_HEIGHT], width=PAD_WIDTH, fill="White")
        self.p2paddle = self.canvas.create_line([WIDTH - HALF_PAD_WIDTH, HEIGHT//2 - HALF_PAD_HEIGHT],
                                                    [WIDTH - HALF_PAD_WIDTH, HEIGHT//2 + HALF_PAD_HEIGHT], width=PAD_WIDTH, fill="White")

    def draw(self):
        if self.keys.get(P2_UP) and self.canvas.coords(self.p1paddle)[1] > 0:
            self.canvas.move(self.p1paddle, 0, -VELOCITY)
        if self.keys.get(P2_DOWN) and self.canvas.coords(self.p1paddle)[3] < HEIGHT:
            self.canvas.move(self.p1paddle, 0, VELOCITY)
        if self.keys.get(P1_UP) and self.canvas.coords(self.p2paddle)[1] > 0:
            self.canvas.move(self.p2paddle, 0, -VELOCITY)
        if self.keys.get(P1_DOWN) and self.canvas.coords(self.p2paddle)[3] < HEIGHT:
            self.canvas.move(self.p2paddle, 0, VELOCITY)

        self.after(10, self.draw)

    def keydown(self, key):
        self.keys[key.keycode] = True

    def keyup(self, key):
        self.keys[key.keycode] = False

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    example = Example(root)
    example.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Perhaps, by chance, some improvement in there will fix your original problem too.

Comment: Unfortunately this still didn't work for me.  Either it's something with MacOSX, or Tkinter interpets key press commands differently in Python 2, than it does in Python 3.  I'm still relatively new to tkinter, and I guess all of the concepts that I was taught to use with SimpleGUI don't really transfer over, like the professor's said they would.  Thanks for the tips though, I'll look into using them to update my main game code.

Comment: I don't see why it would help, but as a shot in the dark you could try installing python3 which comes with an updated version of tcl (the engine behind tkinter).

Comment: @Travis: another shot in the dark: try using the `key.keycode` instead of `key.keysym`. I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: FWIW I tested this in python2.7 and python3.6, and it works fine for me.

Comment: I retested both your code and mine in python 3, prior to switching over to key.keycode, and it worked perfectly!  Using key.keycode did not work for me in python 2.7 either.  I'm still baffled as why it's refusing to work in python 2 for me, though.  I guess that's a question that may never be answered.  Thanks for all of your help!